# RODBC management of dates from SQL server

Tags: sql-server, r, date

I have a SQL database (2012) that I am trying to access through R (R Studio). From Enterprise Manager this is what it looks like:

```
select top 5[date],value from dbo.history

1991-02-11  11.1591

1991-02-12  11.2

1991-02-13  11.3501

1991-02-14  11.37

1991-02-15  11.3002
```

However from R this is what I get:

```
sqlQuery(DF_CN,'select top 5 [date],value from dbo.history')
         date value
1  0011-02-19 11.16

2  0012-02-19 11.20

3  0013-02-19 11.35

4  0014-02-19 11.37

5  0015-02-19 11.30
```

When I try and select all the data from the table, this is what I get

```
sqlQuery(DF_CN,'select * from dbo.history')
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

It may to be something about the yyyy-mm-dd default format from SQL server which I can change if I use `CONVERT`, but this looks like a hack and the `SELECT *` would not work.

Is there something in R I can do to recognise the SQL Server dates?

Ben

---

This is driving me nuts - surely someone has seen this before - there is a clear disconnect between the SQL Server output and what R is reading.

I am using RStudio 0.98.1091 and R x64 3.1.2.
Sql Server 2014
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      12.0.2000.8
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML                                             3.0 4.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                                 9.10.9200.17148
Microsoft .NET Framework                                    4.0.30319.18444
Operating System                                            6.1.7601

ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server.

Everything looks up to date on my system.

the `[date]` column was of type `DATE`, is now `DATETIME`. I now get this;

```
sqlQuery(DF_CN,('select * from dbo.history')

 Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

It looks like some disconnect between SQL server setup and R setup.

Comment: Are you storing the dates as DATETIME values or VARCHAR values in your SQL table? In case of the latter, consider changing them to DATETIME values, which should be handled better by R.

Comment: Dates are stored as DATETIME in the SQL Server Database

Answer (score 13):

I worked it out by using the `as.is` parameter:

```
sqlQuery(DF_CN,'select * from dbo.history',as.is=T)
```

Then casting the values I needed directly in R.

Comment: Thanks much for this suggestion, its works in my case! :)

Comment: This also works in sqlFetch(DF_CN, "table name", as.is = T)

Answer (score 6):

I have worked it out.

Driver set to SQL server Native Client 11.0
ODBC settings - `Use regional settings when outputting currency, numbers, dates and times` switched off.

I am thinking that SQL Server has its own ideas on regional settings rather than what has been provided by windows causing great confusion.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to come back and post the answer, you've made the internet a smarter place :). SQL Server `DATE` and `DATETIME` data types _have no format_. It's only when you select them out that you might choose to format them. Ideally you would never let this data be anything other than a temporal data type, so you'd never have this issue. However when moving data between different systems, this is a frequent problem. It appears that somewhere between the Native Client driver and R, this data is converted to a string.

Comment: I changed the settings as mentioned above and even applied `as.is=T` but i am still getting the error