# as.POSIXlt.character fail on 1975-04-01

Tags: r, posixct, rodbc

Why does `as.POSIXlt.character` fail on this specific date 1975-04-01?

```
> as.POSIXlt.character('1975-04-01')
Error in as.POSIXlt.character("1975-04-01") : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
> as.POSIXlt.character('1975-04-02')
[1] "1975-04-02 CDT"
> as.POSIXlt.character('1975-05-01')
[1] "1975-05-01 CDT"
```

Giving it a `tz = 'GMT'` or `format = '%Y-%m-%d'` both seem to work.

But what can I do if I don't have access to this function? This comes from bumping into this issue [RODBC management of dates from SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27424470/1568919), where `RODBC::sqlQuery` refuses to read any data covering that date, due to `as.POSIXlt.character` error.

Locale info below.

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"
```

Comment: Weird. I can't reproduce your error on my R session.

Comment: Same here. No error, too. Have you tried to define the `format` of your character in `as.POSIXlt.character`?

Comment: what is your locale? it's possible there was something strange in your local time zone back then

Comment: @smoff Give it a `format = '%Y-%m-%d'` works as well. The problem is what to do when I don't have access to those arguments

Comment: @MichaelChirico, please see my edit